# Continue and break statement error in do..while loop

Tags: c, string, break, continue

To be specific ,I want to introduce different cars with 6 districts which are declared in the begining. The program ask me what district appart the car and if the input is the same ,I will continue with car's details ,if not ,I want to come back to district reading. My problem is when I read the first district corectly ,the program works fine and return to district reading ,but at the second one ,is not working anymore. I will attach the code above. I need to mention that is the first time when I use 'continue' and 'break' statement and I think that's the main problem. Thanks !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct record {
    char name[15];
    int year[4];
    char serial[15];
    char owner[24];
    char plate[12];
};

int main() {
    struct record rec[100];
    char search[20];
    int imax=0;
    int i=0,j=0;
    char n;
    char* district[]=     {"Rahova","Giulesti","Crangasi","Militari","Pantelimon","Ferentari"};
    char district_input[20];


printf("\nEnter the cars: ");
do {
    printf("\nCar's number %d -> Enter district: ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",district_input);
    for (;j<=5;j++) {
        if(strcmp(district_input,district[j])==0){
            printf("\t\t    ->Name of the car: ");
            scanf("%s",rec[i].name);
            printf("\t\t    ->Release year: ");
            scanf("%d",rec[i].year);
            printf("\t\t    ->Serial number: ");
            scanf("%s",rec[i].serial);
            printf("\t\t    ->Number plate: ");
            scanf("%s",rec[i].plate);
            printf("\t\t    ->Last 3 owners: ");
            scanf("%s",rec[i].owner);
            printf("\nAdd more? [y/n]\t");
            i++;
            imax++;
            break;
        } 
        continue;
    }
    printf("\nAdd more? [y/n]\t");
} while ((n=getche()) != 'n');

}
```

Comment: The `continue` at the end of the `for` loop has no effect. Not sure what is not clear; read about the two statements in your C book.

Answer (score 1):

`break` and `continue` don't do what you think they do. They only apply to the inner-most loop inside which they are written. In this case the for loop. They have nothing to do with the outer while loop.

Thus for example

```
for (;j<=5;j++) {
  ...
  continue
}
```

is identical to

```
for (;j<=5;j++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I thought ( and i understand from the sintaxe) that if I put the `break` in if statement ,the for loop will end and reload everytime when I reach the frist input